# android.text.format.DateFormat "EEEE" gives wrong day name

Tags: android

I use android.text.format.DateFormat to format date in readable format like this:

```
android.text.format.DateFormat df = new android.text.format.DateFormat();
Date current = new Date();
String day = df.format("EEEE", current).toString();
```

For example today, 23.06.2014 is monday, but this code gives sunday. Date and time on the phone where I test my application are set correctly. Also 12.06.2014 this code prints as friday, but friday was 13 ...

Comment: please show us Your relevant part of code. Also, I would prefere to use Calendar instead of Date, because the most methods of Date are deprecated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry everybody, just writing wrong year to sqllite database ...

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can do alternatively.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy, HH:mm");
String date = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

Log.d("Date->",date);

//Specifically if you want to print day
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE");
        String date = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

        Log.d("------------Date->",date);

 DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE");
 String day= df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

        Log.d("------------Day->",day);
```

Whereas you can have DateFormat patterns such as:

```
"yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z" ----> 2001.07.04 AD at 12:08:56 PDT
"hh 'o''clock' a, zzzz" -----------> 12 o'clock PM, Pacific Daylight Time
"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"-------> Wed, 4 Jul 2001 12:08:56 -0700
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"-------> 2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-0700
"yyMMddHHmmssZ"--------------------> 010704120856-0700
"K:mm a, z" -----------------------> 0:08 PM, PDT
"h:mm a" --------------------------> 12:08 PM
"EEE, MMM d, ''yy" ----------------> Wed, Jul 4, '01
```

For more you can refer -> [Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 1):

## Time Zone

My guess is time zone. Your computer/JVM is set to a default time zone that is different from the time zone in your mind.

A better practice is to always explicitly specify the desired time zone rather than rely on implicit default.

## Joda-Time

Here is example code in Joda-Time 2.3.

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );
DateTime nowParis = DateTime.now( timeZone );
DateTime nowUtc = now.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SimpleDateFormat` instead of `dateFormat`

```
   SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
   Date current = new Date();
   String day = df.format(current).toString();
```

and import `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`

Answer (score 0):

use java date formats.

```
SimpleDateFormat inFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date date = inFormat.parse(input);
SimpleDateFormat outFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
String day = outFormat.format(date);
```

Regards.